# google oauth 404 for page https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_US

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

I have been using Google API Client (gapi.auth.authorize) to handle oAuth and it has been working for months until last night.  It started with an error saying something like "_.Uu is not a function" last night, and this morning the api URL becomes inaccessible completely (returning 404):

[https://apis.google.com/*/scs/apps-static/*/js/k=oz.gapi.en_US.wLUinxMaFvQ.O/m=/exm=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=IQ/rs=AItRSTNDbsyHH46eCqa0_JZmh883Ddz23Q/cb=gapi.loaded_1](https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_US.wLUinxMaFvQ.O/m=/exm=client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=IQ/rs=AItRSTNDbsyHH46eCqa0_JZmh883Ddz23Q/cb=gapi.loaded_1)

Is anyone seeing the same problem? Not sure if Google is making any changes.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

You need to update the [client library](https://apis.google.com/js/client.js) and then it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue is being discussed on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619533/gapi-auth-authorize-typeerror-uu-is-not-a-function). It appears that Google knows about it and [is working on it](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/issues/detail?id=103&sort=-id#makechanges).

Comment: Any word on this? The link above showing that google "is working on it" is broken. Could you re-link please?

Comment: It looks like it was [fixed earlier this month](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/103).