# gapi.auth.authorize: TypeError: _.Uu is not a function

Tags: javascript, authentication

My web applicaion uses google javascript client APIs and it dosen't work since yesterday. An error message occured in Firefox console like: **TypeError: _.Uu is not a function**

what is the reason for this issue?

Comment: Can you please add some more information about what you tried and where exactly the error occurs?

Comment: It is the same problem written in this website: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617359/google-oauth-404-for-page-https-apis-google-com-scs-apps-static-js-k-oz-ga

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Google [fixed this problem](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/103) earlier this month. You have to follow the chain, but this was originally [problem 104](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/104) until it was merged in with problem 103. The solution was rolled out early January.